# Delete row in mysql using AJAX / jQuery (Zend Framework 1.12)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, zend-framework

I am trying to delete a row in my MYSQL db using AJAX/jQuery when the button Delete is pressed. I am using Zend Framework 1.12.

Until the part of alert(del_id) my code is 
working properly: when I press the button Delete, shows a window with the matching id.

But the part of deleting the row in the page and in my data base is not working. Could someone show me the problem?

Also I had some doubts using $.ajax() and Zend: is right put in the url the path to my view script of the delete action?? Doing this way would be calling my deleteAction() function on my controller?

This is the layout with the java script:

```
 <!-- application/views/scripts/users-data/adminpage.phtml -->

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(

function(){
    $(".delete_class").click(
        function(){
            var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent(); 
            alert(del_id);
            $.ajax({type:'POST',
            url:'/users-data/delete.phtml',
            data: {'delete_id':del_id},
            success:function(data) {
            if(data=="YES") {   
                rowElement.fadeOut().remove(); 
                alert("success");
            }else { alert("erro");
            }}
            });     
        });
});

</script>
</head>


<body>
<center>

<?php         
echo "Users List";
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>

</tr>
<?php foreach($this->entries as $entry) : ?>
<tr>

    <td><?php echo $entry->name;?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $entry->email;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entry->id;?></td>
    <td> <button id="<?php echo $entry->id; ?>" class="delete_class"> Delete</button></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And this is the code in the controller:

The deleteUser() function I tested and worked.

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    //$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
    $request = $this->getRequest(); 
    $id= $request->getPost('delete_id');
    $mapper = new Application_Model_UsersDataMapper();
    $mapper->deleteUser($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the problem. As imagined the problem was the url.

I replaced

```
url:'/users-data/delete.phtml',
```

by

```
url:"<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'users-data', 'action' => 'delete')); ?>",
```

and on the condition of if I put: data!="YES".